# Will a stationary charge experience force kept near a current carrying conductor due to electric field from voltage source

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-circuits, electricity, electric-fields

I was studying electricity then I found a statement which states that there is an electric field inside and outside the wire due to the voltage source. So I was thinking will a stationary charge kept near it will experience a force or not according to me it should experience a force

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is an E field outside the wire then a free charge outside the wire will indeed experience a force from that E field. However, the mere fact that three is a current in a wire does not imply that such an E field is present. For instance, a loop of superconducting wire can carry very large currents even without any E field being present.

So your idea that a voltage source implies a force is correct. But the idea that a current implies a voltage source is not always correct.